# Referencing a calculated value from a cross-tab query in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, crosstab

To start off, I would classify myself as a relatively new MS Access user (had to teach myself for work) and have encountered a problem. I have a cross-tab query (code displayed below) with the resulting datasheet resembling the desired results picture attached (excluding the **% of total** column). I would like to be able to reference the **Sum** total from the **Total Spend** row in all three of the **% of total** columns. This has proven to be a harder task than I initially had thought.

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Table1.Amount) AS SumOfAmount
SELECT tblSpendCat.SPEND_CAT, tblSpendCat.SPEND_DESC, Sum(Table1.Amount) AS Totals
FROM tblSpendCat INNER JOIN (tblType INNER JOIN (tblOrg INNER JOIN Table1 ON tblOrg.ID = Table1.tblORG_ID) ON tblType.ID = Table1.tblType_ID) ON tblSpendCat.ID = Table1.tblSpendCat_ID
WHERE (((tblSpendCat.SPEND_CAT)="Total_Spend" Or (tblSpendCat.SPEND_CAT)="Supplies" Or (tblSpendCat.SPEND_CAT)="Other Costs" Or (tblSpendCat.SPEND_CAT)="Misc") AND ((Table1.mnth)>"April") AND ((tblOrg.Org)="Org1" Or (tblOrg.Org)="Org2" Or (tblOrg.Org)="Org3" Or (tblOrg.Org)="Org4" Or (tblOrg.Org)="Org5" Or (tblOrg.Org)="Org6" Or (tblOrg.Org)="Org7"))
GROUP BY tblSpendCat.SPEND_CAT, tblSpendCat.SPEND_DESC
PIVOT Table1.mnth;
```

**What I have tried:**

1. I queried the specific **Total Spend** value in a separate stand-alone query and attempted to reference it in the main cross-tab query in a new expression field: **results returned from the separate, stand-alone query :**

   [image]
2. Tried referencing the calculated value directly from the main cross-tab query (the same main cross-tab query referenced in this post) in a new expression field in the same main cross-tab query

**Desired Results:**

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Best,

James

Comment: You save total spent as a category in table? Shouldn't total spent be aggregate calculation from all other category data? Will probably have to build another query that joins the crosstab to another query with the total calc so it is available on each row. Or don't include Total_Spend category in the crosstab and build a report based on crosstab and use report Sorting & Grouping with aggregate calcs to calculate total and percentage.

Comment: **Total Spend** is an allocation of funds, like you are allocated _x_ amount for **Supplies** and **Other Costs**. It is possible to over spend beyond the set amount. My poor naming choices didn't help me get that point across. My apologies!. The **Total Spend** Sum can be smaller than the combined Sums of both **Supplies** and **Other Costs**. I will try and build another query and join it with the crosstab. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for the suggestions @June7 !